# How to change timestamp format on rsyslog

Tags: datetime, timestamp, rsyslog, formatdatetime

I want to change the default timestamp format on rsyslog. Currently I am running on RHEL7.2. Syslog version 7.4.7. Now the default format is the following:

```
Mar 23 09:35:30 localhost DEB  [9125:<console>.<module>:2] debug info
```

Inside rsyslog.conf I have define the following template:

```
$template Mytemplate,"%timegenerated% %HOSTNAME% %syslogseverity-text:0:3:uppercase% %msg%\n"
```

How can I change the format to this YYYY-MM-dd H:i:s ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The modification is the following:

```
$template Mytemplate,"%$year%-%$month%-%$day% %timegenerated:12:19:date-rfc3339% %HOSTNAME% %syslogseverity-text:0:3:uppercase% %msg%\n"
```

Comment: Thank you for a clear and detailed question, and a specific usable answer!